# Parsing data from function to android app

Tags: android, weather-api, google-weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

This code gets data from weatherunderground api. I'm building android app that uses this data in internal functions. I'm having problems using this data in android app code.

```
package perry.test;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{

    // enter zip here
    WeatherInfo weather = new WeatherInfo(48104);

    // variables for today
    System.out.println(weather.cur);
    System.out.println(weather.cur_high_c);
    System.out.println(weather.cur_high_f);
    System.out.println(weather.cur_low_c);
    System.out.println(weather.cur_low_f);
    System.out.println(weather.cur_cond);

}
}
```

Attempts: I copy and pasted the code that uses class with all the needed info about the weather, then i have a variable that i want to assign value from weather class.

Errors that i get: Eclipse tells me to surround with catch and try, when i surround it my entire app doesn't load to emulator at all.

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Regular constructors
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    // Load the preferences file for the settings
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("weatherapp_settings",MODE_PRIVATE);


    // Check for values, set to default if not available
    boolean get_is_male = prefs.getBoolean("is_male", true);
    boolean get_is_metric = prefs.getBoolean("is_metric", false);
    int get_temperature = prefs.getInt("temperature", 72);
    int get_zipcode = prefs.getInt("zipcode", 48109);


// Create the listener for the temperature slider
    bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_temp);
    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        // Set the temperature from the progress bar
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            setTemperature(progress);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


    //Loading only default settings
    // Update the settings page
    if (get_is_male)
    {
        setMale(null);
    } 
    else
    {
        setFemale(null);
    }
    if (get_is_metric)
    {
        setCelsius(null);
    } 
    else 
    {
        setFahrenheit(null);
    }

    setZipCode(get_zipcode);

    setTemperature(get_temperature);
    WeatherInfo weather = new WeatherInfo(48104);
            curTemp = weather.cur_high_c;

    // variables for today
    System.out.println(weather.cur);
    System.out.println(weather.cur_high_c);
    System.out.println(weather.cur_high_f);
    System.out.println(weather.cur_low_c);
    System.out.println(weather.cur_low_f);
    System.out.println(weather.cur_cond);       


}
```

Logcat:

```
12-03 07:27:32.219: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:32.219: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:32.230: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:32.430: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:32.430: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:33.949: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:33.949: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:33.949: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:33.970: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.030: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.030: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.040: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.100: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.130: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.130: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.141: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.141: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.141: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.160: D/gralloc_goldfish(808): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-03 07:27:34.250: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.300: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.350: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.350: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.709: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:34.709: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.450: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.461: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.461: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.461: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.480: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.480: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.560: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.560: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.670: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.730: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.730: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.730: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.799: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.799: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.799: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:36.869: D/dalvikvm(808): GC_CONCURRENT freed 93K, 8% free 2714K/2924K, paused 6ms+26ms, total 241ms
12-03 07:27:37.440: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:37.460: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:37.600: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:37.690: D/android.widget.GridLayout(808): horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=712, x2-x1<=224, x1-x0<=136 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x1<=224. 
12-03 07:27:37.710: D/android.widget.GridLayout(808): horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=712, x2-x1<=60, x1-x0<=148 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x1<=60. 
12-03 07:27:37.730: D/android.widget.GridLayout(808): horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=712, x2-x1<=22, x1-x0<=186 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x1<=22. 
12-03 07:27:37.741: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:37.820: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:37.860: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:37.860: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:37.880: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:37.880: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:37.979: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:37.979: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:38.039: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:38.049: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:38.109: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:38.119: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:38.149: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:38.149: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:38.359: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:38.460: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:38.490: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:38.530: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.389: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.389: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.419: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.419: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.809: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.820: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.830: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.830: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.850: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.850: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.950: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:39.950: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.080: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.090: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.100: D/android.widget.GridLayout(808): horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=712, x2-x1<=224, x1-x0<=136 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x1<=224. 
12-03 07:27:40.110: D/android.widget.GridLayout(808): horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=712, x2-x1<=174, x1-x0<=148 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x1<=174. 
12-03 07:27:40.120: D/android.widget.GridLayout(808): horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=712, x2-x1<=136, x1-x0<=186 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x1<=136. 
12-03 07:27:40.120: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.120: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.140: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.140: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.209: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.209: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.850: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.860: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.870: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.920: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.920: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.920: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.950: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:40.950: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.070: D/dalvikvm(808): GC_CONCURRENT freed 118K, 8% free 2993K/3228K, paused 5ms+21ms, total 57ms
12-03 07:27:41.100: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.110: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.120: D/android.widget.GridLayout(808): horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=712, x2-x1<=224, x1-x0<=136 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x1<=224. 
12-03 07:27:41.130: D/android.widget.GridLayout(808): horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=712, x2-x1<=174, x1-x0<=148 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x1<=174. 
12-03 07:27:41.130: D/android.widget.GridLayout(808): horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=712, x2-x1<=136, x1-x0<=186 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x1<=136. 
12-03 07:27:41.140: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.140: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.150: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.150: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.190: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.190: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.920: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.930: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.939: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.970: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.970: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:41.979: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:42.010: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:42.010: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:42.050: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:42.050: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:42.062: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:42.070: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:42.070: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:42.070: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:42.100: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:42.100: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.460: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.460: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.490: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.500: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.520: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.589: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.589: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.599: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.609: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.649: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.659: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:43.659: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:44.240: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:44.340: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:44.380: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:44.380: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:44.689: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:44.689: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:44.699: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:44.909: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:45.090: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:45.340: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:45.700: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:45.700: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:45.730: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:45.749: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.259: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.279: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.290: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.290: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.290: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.310: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.390: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.390: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.460: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.536: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.536: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.540: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.560: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.560: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:46.590: W/Trace(808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:27:47.129: D/AndroidRuntime(808): Shutting down VM
12-03 07:27:47.129: W/dalvikvm(808): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.weatherapp/com.example.weatherapp.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at com.example.weatherapp.SettingsActivity.setZipCode(SettingsActivity.java:203)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at com.example.weatherapp.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:90)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-03 07:27:47.159: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  ... 11 more
12-03 07:27:47.199: D/dalvikvm(808): GC_CONCURRENT freed 89K, 6% free 3365K/3572K, paused 6ms+77ms, total 173ms
12-03 07:27:50.980: I/Process(808): Sending signal. PID: 808 SIG: 9
12-03 07:28:25.781: E/Trace(886): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-03 07:28:25.781: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:25.781: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:25.790: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:26.129: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:26.181: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.519: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.519: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.529: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.549: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.609: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.609: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.609: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.749: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.759: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.759: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.759: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.769: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.769: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.789: D/gralloc_goldfish(886): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-03 07:28:27.900: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:27.939: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.059: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.090: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.119: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.119: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.270: D/dalvikvm(886): GC_CONCURRENT freed 95K, 8% free 2696K/2908K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 202ms
12-03 07:28:30.290: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.290: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.311: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.340: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.410: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.470: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.480: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.480: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.680: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.680: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:30.680: W/Trace(886): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-03 07:28:31.259: D/AndroidRuntime(886): Shutting down VM
12-03 07:28:31.259: W/dalvikvm(886): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.weatherapp/com.example.weatherapp.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at com.example.weatherapp.SettingsActivity.setZipCode(SettingsActivity.java:203)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at com.example.weatherapp.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:90)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-03 07:28:31.299: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  ... 11 more
12-03 07:28:31.470: D/dalvikvm(886): GC_CONCURRENT freed 109K, 8% free 3015K/3244K, paused 11ms+43ms, total 195ms
```

Comment: What was the o/p of LogCat?

Comment: Console:
Installation failed due to invalid URI!
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!

Comment: So, did you see the o/p of LogCat?.Go to Window > Show View > Others > Android > LogCat. Paste the o/p here.

Comment: May I recommend that you learn Java and OOP first, then try a simple Android tutorial before trying to copy/paste a working application together?  You will save yourself a lot of time.